# TypeError: center() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python

how to print :`#*#*gudu*#*#.`
when I try to print this error comes like this-`TypeError: center() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)`.plz help

```
name="gudu"
print(name.center(11,'@',12,'#'))
```

here I have tried to pass both * and # and their numbers.

```
name="gudu"
print(name.center(11,'@',12,'#'))
```

`#*#*gudu*#*#`    (it is the expected output)

Comment: What's wrong with `'#*#*{}*#*#'.format(name)`?

Comment: If you want to use center() function, read its description first.

Comment: Center only accepts 2 arguments at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The better thing to do would be to use something like `print('#*#*{}*#*#'.format(name))`  or even better if you're using python 3.6 or higher, you can use f-strings: `print(f'#*#*{name}*#*#')`

Center isn't a good use-case if you're looking to do more than one character surrounding the string.

EDIT: To choose how much padding goes into it, you can multiply your string pattern by an inputted number.

```
name = "gudu"
pattern_size = 3
padding = '*#' * pattern_size      # gives '*#*#*#' when pattern_size = 3
string = padding+name+padding
print(string)
```

Comment: And `center` only takes 1 char. So your code doesn't work

Comment: And edited to reflect

Comment: can you tell me how can I give input how may * and # to print in this question

Comment: You added an edit. You sure the output `string` is the same as the OP expected? It doesn't seem to be same

Comment: Remember to read the entire context of the post. The edit was in response to the question that OP asked just above your response, of how to give an input to change the length of the pattern.

Comment: There is difference between `#*#*gudu*#*#` (By OP) and `*#*#gudu*#*#*` (your edit)

Comment: I was answering the question of how to give an input to change the length of the pattern. I answered his initial question, and then pointed him in the right direction for a followup question. I don't think I need to hold OP's hand quite that much.

Comment: If you are saying that, this is not the correct answer to @pratyus . Because it doesn't give OP's expected output

Comment: You might need to read the question again. Also you just added that piece of code in your answer added in [the comment by @Aran-Fey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636001/typeerror-center-takes-at-most-2-arguments-4-given/57636054#comment101724726_57636001)

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for `.center()` function is `center(width, [fillChar])`.

**Width** is the total string length after padding the characters.

**fillChar** is optional, by default it pads the whitespace unless any character is provided.

Your code should be:

```
name='gudu'
print(name.center(12,'#'))   # fillChar should be only one character long
```

Sample Output:

[image]

For reference, [click here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/center).

Answer (score 0):

I made a function `center_` to put multiple chars on the right and left side of the string. It takes four arguments

- `string` (string you want to center)
- `width` (width for left and right side chars, `2` means two times the left and right side chars on each side)
- `lchars` (left side chars)
- `rchars` (right side chars)

Function:

```
def center_(string, width, lchars, rchars):
    return lchars*width + string + rchars*width
```

Testing with your example:

```
>>> name = "gudu"
>>> center_(name, 2, "#*", "*#")
'#*#*gudu*#*#'
>>>
```